# Last element breaking all siblings in absolute positions

Tags: html, css

I have a container div which has 5 images, all absolutely positioned. I've added the top and left values for all of them but as soon as you define the last element as absolutely positioned, all other images lose their positions and stact at the top.

The container is relatively positioned

```
.responsive-container{
   position: relative;
}
```

And it has the images inside

```
<img src="img/responsive-mac.png" id="res-mac">
<img src="img/responsive-laptop.png" id="res-lap">
<img src="img/responsive-tab.png" id="res-tab">
<img src="img/responsive-phone-portrait.png" id="res-ph-1">
<img src="img/responsive-phone-landscape.png" id="res-ph-2">
```

With following Css applied

```
.responsive-container{
    position: relative;
}
#res-mac{
    position: absolute;  width: 97%;  top: 0%;
}
#res-lap{
    position: absolute; width: 85%;  top: 232%;  left: 30%;
}
#res-tab{
    position: absolute;  width: 35%; top: 414%;  left: 7%;
}
#res-ph-1{
    position: absolute;  width: 20%;  top: 573%;  left: 36%;
}
#res-ph-2{
    position: absolute;  width: 25%;  top: 26%;  left: 28%;
}
```

In the [demo](http://bwdmedia.in/testbench/webdev/demo.html) here, you can just remove the `position: absolute;` from the 5th image and others would start working. It's not that particular image which is the problem, if you remove the 5th image completely, the 4th image will start doing the same thing.

I've tried removing all css and javascript to narrow down the cause but it;s still not working. What gives?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Also, absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out pages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: That's a very good point @Paulie_D , I've added the code to the question and about absolute positions, well I gotta put up parallax effects there hence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.responsive-container { height: 66px; }
```

Comment: That worked. Can you explain the reason behind the issue?

Comment: This div has relative position, but has no height. That is the point. Browser can not understand position in % from zero height.

Comment: There is also better solution: to make mac-image position relatively - in this case you will need to correct vertical position of all other images, but on small screen all images will resize proportionally.